# When VS Edit and Continue needs a recompile?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

In which cases of Visual Studio '**Edit and Continue**' feature do i have to rebuild / restart the project (otherwise the changes don't influence the running process)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean "Edit and Continue"? If so, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164927.aspx) are the supported code changes for c#, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba77s56w.aspx) are the vb ones and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dbey757.aspx) for visual c++.